# Using for loop to name vector

Tags: r, list, loops, vector, naming

I am using a for loop to read in several tables, while reading in these tables I would like to generate lists from a specific column in each data frame and name that list using a variable.

The idea is to use a list such as Names in example below, which can then be used to assign vector names to lists as they are brought in.

```
Names <- list("1","2","3")


Tables <- list.files(".",recursive = T, pattern = ".csv", full.names=T)

for (file in Tables)
{
 print(file)
 df <- read.csv(file, header =T)
 list <- list(df$1)
}
```

What is the best appraoch to end up with a results that gives me lists named list_1, list_2, and list_3 from the example above?

thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)    

Tables <- list.files(path = ".",
               recursive = T,
               pattern = ".csv",
               full.names = T) %>% 
      map(~read_csv(.)) %>% 
      set_names(., nm = paste0("list_", Names))

list2env(Tables, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```